# How to get the logger of a class in a static context?

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying to recieve the logger for my class:

```
public static final java.util.logging.Logger log = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this);
```

But using "this" there causes "Cannot use this in a static context" error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: I must be able to access the logger from all classes in my program, so it *must* be public.

Comment: Are you using Log4J or `java.util.logging` (what is the package of `Logger`)?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I used `java.util.logging`. Edited my post now to make that clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice I changed modifier from `public` to `private`:

```
public class FooBar {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooBar.class);

    //or (if you are using java.util.logging):

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooBar.class.getName());


}
```

Comment: checkstyle: Please write log in Capital Letters "LOG"

Comment: @AlexWien: well, actually I prefer small letters, but I understand why we should use `LOG` (in capitals).

Comment: But I want to be able to access the logger from _all classes in my program_, I don't think I can do that if I make it private? (added it to my question)

Comment: @com.BOY: each class is suppose to have its own logger. That's the point, in the logs you'll see which class logged given message for free. Unless you have a really good reason. But typically one class -> one logger. Of course you *can* make it public, but then no matter which class will use it, you'll always see `FooBar` in the logs, which is at least counterintuitive.

Answer (score 7):

For org.appache.log4j:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

For java.util.Logging

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Comment: Note that he is apparently using `java.util.logging` which does not accept `Class` as an argument, only Strings

Comment: Why do you think that he is using java.util.Logging; Most use org.appache Log4j

Comment: It is not at all apparent that he is using java.util.logging

Comment: @Perception: you are both right, I only compared `java.util.logging` API with SLF4J (which is different), I'll ask OP. +1 to Alex.

Comment: I am using `java.util.logging`, edited my question now to make that clear.

Comment: I, too changed from public to private, this is a deviation of your original code, but it is better.

Comment: In your latest edit you added solution for both `java.util.logging` and Log4J. You mixed the samples, it should be the other way around...

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I started with log4j, in the text, then copied up util.logging because it is the desired answer.